# Spring Data: update @query or find+save?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am pretty new to spring and spring data and I would like to know what's considered to be the best practice for updating entities in the database.

Should I write a custom query in my repository like

```
@Query("update Person set email = :email where id = :id)
```

Or should I use something like

```
onePerson = repository.findOneById(id);
onePerson.setEmail(email);
repository.save(onePerson);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former `@Query` example will provide much better performance since you don't need to pull down the data and instantiate the object. However, if you need the object downstream for additional business logic, the 2nd approach may be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Modifying` like below:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.firstname = ?1 where u.lastname = ?2")
int setFixedFirstnameFor(String firstname, String lastname);
```

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: Yes, I do have @ Modifying and @ Transactional annotations. My question was about performance and best practices. Thank you anyway :)